# Как перебрать коллекцию элементов?

Tags: javascript, циклы, события

HTML:

```
<div class="info-block">
  <img src="photo.jpg" alt="фотография" class="hidden">
  <img src="photo2.jpg" alt="фотография" class="hidden">
  <inframe width="789" height="444" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QHFhIjF2L0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen class="hidden">
</div>
<div class="info-block">
  <img src="photo.jpg" alt="фотография" class="hidden">
  <img src="photo2.jpg" alt="фотография" class="hidden">
  <inframe width="789" height="444" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QHFhIjF2L0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen class="hidden">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
function show(){
    var button = document.querySelector('.info-block');
    var img = document.querySelector('img');
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');

    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        iframe.classList.toggle('hidden');
        img.classList.toggle('hidden');
    });
};

show();
```

Код должен скрывать и показывать картинки и видео по щелчку на `<div class="display-block">`. Он это делает, но только для первого изображения и первого видео в первом блоке. На остальные не работает.
Поискав информацию по этой теме, я выяснил, что `button.addEventListener()` не работает для коллекции элементов и при помощи цикла эту коллекцию нужно перебрать и присвоить каждому элементу свой addEventListener. Только вот я так и не понял, как правильно составить такой цикл. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: В вашем случае button это не коллекция объектов, это один HTMLElement

Comment: @Leonid да, спасибо за замечание

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  function show(){
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.info-block');
    buttons.forEach(el => 
      el.addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => img.classList.toggle('hidden'));
        this.querySelector('iframe').classList.toggle('hidden');
      });
    );
  }
```

---

```
  function show(){
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.info-block');
    buttons.forEach(btn => 
      btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('hidden'));
      });
    );
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы помогли.
Задам небольшой вопрос: где можно почитать про этот способ, который вы использовали? Я просто совсем еще зеленый

Comment: @Стогометр https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll